# Problema con formulario en php con mysql y html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Mi formulario en cual es un registro de piloto , donde tienen que ingresar un número único lo que no logro es hacer que  si este numero único ya esta en la base de datos arroje un mensaje de "ese numero ya esta en uso"

este es mi formulario:

```
    <form action="guardarNumero.php" method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="numero"  class="form-control" placeholder="numero de participacion" minlength="1" maxlength="3" required autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="nombre completo" required autofocus>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="rut" class="form-control" placeholder="rut" minlength="9" maxlength="10"required autofocus>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" name="guardarNumero" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Registrar" required>
        </form>
```

y se a través del metodo de POST a este php :

```
    <?php

include('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['guardarNumero'])) {
  $numero = $_POST['numero'];
  //aqui necesito validar 
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $rut = $_POST['rut'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO reservas (nroPiloto,nombre, rut)
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT '$numero' AS NUMEROPILOTO, '$nombre' AS NOM, '$rut' AS RUT,) AS tmp
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT nroPiloto FROM reservas WHERE nroPiloto = '$numero') LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  if(!$result) {
    die("Query Failed.");
  }

  $_SESSION['message'] = 'Piloto Ingresado Exitosamente!';
  $_SESSION['message_type'] = 'success';
  header('Location: reserva.php');
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías poner al campo el indice *unique* para que solo acepte ese número en especifico y no pueda repetirse.
Yo metería la transacción en un try catch para poder mostrar los errores.

```
   <?php
try {
  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tabla (id, numero, campo2, campo3)    
VALUES (NULL, :numero, :campo2, :campo3)");
  $stmt->bindValue(":numero", $_POST['numero']);
  $stmt->bindValue(":campo2", $_POST['campo2']);
  $stmt->bindValue(":campo3", $_POST['campo3']);
  $stmt->execute();
  echo "Agregado correctamente!";
} catch (PDOException $e) {//Para cachar errores de PDO
  echo "Error en la base de datos: Parece que el número ha sido usado con anterioridad.<br>".$e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) { //Excepciones de otro tipo
  echo "Error!: Algo salio mal!.<br>".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Espero que te pueda servir este ejemplo

Comment: lo solucione de la siguiente manera  
[enlace](https://justpaste.it/6g4oo) PD: nose  como responder con codigo